# in callback this refers to window instead of my object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, callback

I am trying to use Google Maps v3 API call in the method of my JS object, but after invoking the callback `this` refers to `window` instead of my `myObj` object.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();   

var myObj = function() {

  this.doSomeWork = function(){
    geocoder.geocode({'address':address}, this._myCallback)
  }

  this._myCallback : function() {
    // now this refers to window !!!
  }    
}    

var obj = new myObj();
obj.doSomeWork();
```

What workaround can I use in this case?